# iterating through two pandas data frames and finding a string from df1 that a is in df2

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframe's, let's call them df1 and df2.

df1

`Term      Served
 term1     82321
 term2     54232
 term3     34323
 term4     1231`

df2

`Full Term               clicks
 this is term1           233
 oh boy this is term2    122
 yea that's right term1  1121
 oh no not that term4    313123`

I would like to go row by row and find every time that the terms in df1 appear in df2. After that I would like to sum all of the clicks for that specific term. The out put would look like,

`Term      Served  Clicks
 term1     82321   1354
 term2     54232   122
 term3     34323   0
 term4     1231    313123`

Here is what I have so far. I haven't gotten past grabing all of the times that the terms in df1 appear in df2. The code below keeps looping through only the first row in df1. Maybe I am not understanding the `str.findall()` or I have my loops wrong.

`for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    for row2 in df2.iteritems():
        full_headline = df2['Full Term'].str.findall(row[0])
        print(full_headline)`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC using `str.findall` extact the Term in df2 from df1 , then we need `gourpby` `sum` the common Term in df2 .So far right now ,we only need assign the result back to df1 using `map`

```
df2['Full Term']=df2['Full Term'].str.findall('|'.join(df1.Term)).str[0]
s=df2.groupby('Full Term').clicks.sum()
df1['Clicks']=df1.Term.map(s).fillna(0)
df1
Out[114]: 
    Term  Served    Clicks
0  term1   82321    1354.0
1  term2   54232     122.0
2  term3   34323       0.0
3  term4    1231  313123.0
```

---

Update if that is the case you may want to see [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939) after `str.findall`

```
df2['Full Term']=df2['Full Term'].str.findall('|'.join(df1.Term))
df2=df2[df2['Full Term'].astype(bool)].copy()#adding here

def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx=df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({x:np.concatenate(df[x].values)} )for x in explode],axis=1)
    df1.index=idx
    return df1.join(df.drop(explode,1),how='left')
s=unnesting(df2,['Full Term']).groupby('Full Term').clicks.sum()
df1['Clicks'] = df1.Term.map(s).fillna(0)
df1
Out[137]: 
    Term  Served  Clicks
0  term1   82321    1354
1  term2   54232     355
2  term3   34323     233
3  term4    1231  313123
```

---

Comment: I tried your code out and ended up with an array of ints containing all click rows for each term. For example, term1 will have 2331121. it seems like it isn't summing but adding the clicks in an array?

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'` here there, thanks for the quick response. when unseating that error us being thrown, I can do some googling on it

Comment: @TimothyMcwilliams adding one line before unnesting

Comment: added the line right before unnesting and still came up with the same result, no error though.